# Isolation within OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

I'm trying to understand the benefits of OSGi and what I can't understand is what happens if one of the user-supplied components crashes (for example with OutOfMemory exception). Will this problem be isolated just to this component or the complete JVM will crash?

Answer (score 3):

OSGi does not provide memory or CPU isolation between bundles or components. All bundles in an OSGi Framework run inside a Java Virtual Machine, and Java itself does not have the capability to offer this kind of isolation. OSGi can only do things that are possible within the standard Java architecture.

If you want greater isolation, then use separate OS processes. Remember though: there is no such thing as perfect isolation. If you run as separate processes there is always the chance that a rogue process can take down the entire OS. Even if you run on a separate computer in the same datacentre, then the next power cut or tsunami will affect both computers. So you have to ask yourself how much isolation is needed, and what specific risks you need to mitigate.

For what it's worth, there was an attempt within Java a long time ago to provide memory and CPU isolation. This was JSR-121 (Application Isolation API) and it was never adopted into Java SE. Some vendors such as IBM and Waratek implemented proprietary isolation/multitenancy, but these did not catch on (Waratek later pivoted to application security). Basically you end up implementing a process scheduler within the JVM, and what's the point when the OS already has a good one?

Answer (score 2):

OSGi isolates components at classloader level, and an OutOfMemoryError occurs at JVM level. OSGi does not provide "memory isolation". To answer shortly: the whole JVM will crash.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi Isolation is related to the class resolution and class loading. JVM process itself is shared. So OOM Exception will affect your whole container

If you want to run a 3rd party component, you may want to create a new instance (managed from your root container), it runs as a separate OS process with separate JVM parameters.